# Remove white space below google map (iframe inserted)

Tags: css, google-maps

I inserted a google map in my site using an iframe.

Problem is that there is a "white space" just below the map.

I already try with:

```
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
```

but not working. 
How can I remove it?

This is the real site (just a the bottom): http://jurisglobal.es/

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this

make line-height:0; for the parent div of iframe.

```
.et_pb_text_inner {
    line-height: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to css file to remove space

```
.et_pb_text_inner iframe{float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of removing that whitespace.

First, you can set the `float` value to `left` or `right`.

```
iframe {
   float: right;
      // or
   float: left;
}
```

This will look identical on your website because you have set the `iframe` `max-height` to `100%`.

```
iframe {
   max-height: 100%;
}
```

float = left:
[image: float: left;]

float = right:
[image]
Secondly, you could set the `div` surrounding the `iframe` `line-height` to `0`

```
.et_pb_row_5 .et_pb_row {
   line-height: 0;
}
```

[image]

Hope this information helps you out.